# Forward path gain

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, gain, convolution

Consider a simple circuit consisting of a pair of wires, where input voltage is equal to output voltage.

Here forward path gain is  G(s) = 1 ,(fig.1) which gives g(t) = δ(t) {Inverse Laplace Transform}. It gives Vo(t) = Vi(t), which comes from convolution of Vi(t) and δ(t) i.e. 'Vo(t) = Vi(t) * δ(t)'.

Now the question is, does transfer function of a pair of wires is δ(t)?
MORE IMPORTANTLY, How can we visualize it?

NOTE : I have taken Vout = Vin for simplicity. Otherwise it  could have been a simple voltage divider circuit.
[image]
[image: Vi(t) is taken constant just for illustration purpose.]

Comment: The LT of \$1\times x(t)\$ is not \$\frac{1}{s}\times X(s)\$;  it's \$X(s)\$. You don't transform constant coefficients, they come straight through the LT unchanged.

Comment: @Chu, but LT of $f(t)g(t)$ is $F(s)* G(s) $, i. e. convolution. So, shouldn't the LT of $1$ or $K$, be $1/s$? where K is a constant. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So, what is the convolution (performed in the s-domain and resulting in a function of time) of F(s) and G(s)? Note \$1\times g(t) = g(t)\$, therefore the laplace transform of \$1\times g(t) = G(s)\$. Another example, \$10=2\times 5\$, therefore  the laplace transform of \$10 = \frac{10}{s}\$, which is not the same as \$\frac{2}{s}\times \frac{5}{s} =\frac{10}{s^2}\$

Comment: @Chu, I see that there is some problem with my understanding of convolution, I am editing this question since my main question of, interpreting the impulse function as the property of wires.